# Making secure authentications in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, next.js, uid

I started using Firebase in my app, and I already have login and signUp with email and password set up. How can I persist this user in my app to make secure authenticated requests and start using Firebase's cloud storage?

I noticed that after the login(or signUp) The user gets an uid. Can this uid be stored in localStorage and be used to make authenticated requests?

I also wanted to ask something related to firebase's possibilities on databases. I'm aware of the existence of cloud firestore and realtime database. The app that I'm building is a simple photoBook where users that are authenticated can create albums, and in this albums they can upload photos. My question is: I have to use Cloud Storage to make the file uploads and the realtime database to handle users and their albums?

Comment: Asking for the best way is kinda opinion based. It might be better to instead ask if a specific way works for a specific reason instead of asking what is best way as that could result in opinionated answers. Might I also point out opinionated answers/questions are a big no-no on SO

Comment: I understand your point, but my main doubt is about the fact that I should or not store an uid in localStorage(or cookies too) to make authenticated requests]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to do is get the UID or ID token of the authenticated user for future use, there's no need to persist anything.  Firebase Auth automatically persists a token for the user (in local storage), and refreshes it periodically.  You don't have to do anything to make that happen.

When you should do is simply [observe the auth state of the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) to find out when the SDK has verified their account.  Or if you need an auth token for calling a backend, there is [another observer for that](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients).

Comment: So in this case, while dealing with secure routes for example, I should just check for a non-null user in my state and redirect people that are no t authenticated?

Comment: Omg I saw you in youtube couple times, just realized it lol . Anyway thanks for the help : )

Comment: If that works for you, sure.